How can I create a type with equality semantics similar to strings
Based on this closed question (which at this time isn't likely to be reopened), the task would be to create an immutable type that

uses a mechanism similar to string.Intern to have the same value instances share the same managed reference.
equality comparison is first done based on ReferenceEquals but then falls back to value semantics, i.e. equality of fields.

In effect something like string.Equals:
public override bool Equals([NotNullWhen(true)] object? obj) {
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
        return true;

    if (obj is not string str)
        return false;

    if (this.Length != str.Length)
        return false;

    return EqualsHelper(this, str);
}

Can we create such a type without the automatic compiler/runtime magic that is used on behalf of strings and also without it being too memory intensive?

For the immutability part (and some help from the compiler for boilerplate code that we would have written ourselves), we could make use of a record type in which we also define

some caching static data structure which keeps already created instances that we can reuse
static factory methods that check if the created instance is already in the cache before returning a new one

The hardest part would be to implement the caching data structure which per the requirements has to be not as memory-intensive, i.e. not keeping all ever created instances inside it for the duration of the AppDomain as interned strings are kept.
A nice built-in type that we could use is the ConditionalWeakTable<OurType,OurType>:

... a key stored in the
ConditionalWeakTable<TKey,TValue> table does not persist after
references to it outside the table are destroyed.

It has self-managing behavior, so that instances don't stay alive forever after they are no longer used - which is what we would want to keep memory lower.
The main issue with it in our case is that it's not a "normal" dictionary in that it doesn't use GetHashCode and Equals to find a match but ReferenceEquals instead. This means that to get the cached instance we would have to have the cached instance already available...
But I think we can create a Dictionary that exhibits a similar behavior ourselves if we define it like: Dictionary<OurType,WeakReference<OurType>>.
So to get to our cached instance we will create a new temporary instance in our factory method. Then we use it as the key (compiler is already kind enough to have overridden GetHashCode for our record) to find the WeakReference<OurType> and then extract its target.
This would allow us to do some cleanup of no-longer referenced instances from the dictionary later. For this to be possible we would need to introduce a bit of a overhead - two duplicate instances with the same value/GetHashCode but different managed references - one for the key in the dictionary and the other for the WeakReference, so that the key doesn't keep the target of the WeakReference alive.
To do the cleanup we can have a manual static ClearCache() method or a bit of finalizer magic to do this automatically. In the latter we would check in the finalizer of an instance if it is in the dictionary and that its managed reference is the same as the one in the WeakReference - then we will remove the dictionary entry. I've left this version commented in the code as I haven't thoroughly tested it (but it looks promising)
sealed record RecordWithIntern(int field) {

    // key and value are different instances
    // with the same members
    // used for disambiguation and auto-cleanup
    // share the same GetHashCode and Equals
    private static Dictionary<RecordWithIntern, WeakReference<RecordWithIntern>>
        s_dictionaryInterns = new();
    public static int CacheCount => s_dictionaryInterns.Count;
    static object lockObject = new Object();

    // same signature as the record constructor
    public static RecordWithIntern CreateOrGetIntern(int field) {
        var newInst = new RecordWithIntern(field);

        lock (lockObject) {
            if (s_dictionaryInterns.TryGetValue(newInst, out var weakReference)) {
                if (weakReference.TryGetTarget(out var actualInstance)) {
                    return actualInstance;
                }
                // if finalizer implementationc we shouldn't
                // have null in any weakReference
                // so this path should be impossible to get to
                // with manual clearCache we would
                weakReference.SetTarget(newInst);
                return newInst;
            }

            // key needs to be different object
            // than the value although the same values
            // alternatively same constructor call
            var key = newInst with {};

            s_dictionaryInterns.Add(key,
                new WeakReference<RecordWithIntern>(newInst,
                trackResurrection: true)); // for auto-cleanup in finalizer
            return newInst;

        }
    }
    public static void ClearCache() {
        lock (lockObject) {
            var deadObjects = s_dictionaryInterns
                .Where(kvp => kvp.Value.TryGetTarget(out _) == false)
                .Select(x => x.Key)
                .ToList();

            foreach (var dead in deadObjects) {
                s_dictionaryInterns.Remove(dead);
            }
        }
    }

    // We get GetHashCode for free from the compiler
    // suppress the warning here
    // or define our own get HashCode
    // with the same logic
    public bool Equals(RecordWithIntern other) {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(other, null)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (object.ReferenceEquals(other, this)) {
            return true;
        }

        // need to implement the value-equality
        // ourselves
        return this.field.Equals(other.field);
    }


    //alternative to ClearCahce -> finalizer - self-cleaning
    //~RecordWithIntern() {
    //    // we need to lock because
    //    // if we don't we will be getting a reference
    //    // in the Create Factory to something that's about to be removed
    //    // so the next time we will recreate the entry
    //    // and we will have different references for the same value
    //    lock (lockObject) {
    //        if (s_dictionaryInterns.TryGetValue(this, out var weakReference)
    //        && weakReference.TryGetTarget(out var actualInstance)
    //        && object.ReferenceEquals(this, actualInstance)) {
    //            // needs resurection tracking for the Weak Reference
    //            s_dictionaryInterns.Remove(this);
    //        }
    //    }
    //}

}

And some tests:
// TEST in Release Mode / TieredCompilation turned off on .NET Core3+

Console.WriteLine("--- Simple Tests ---");
var c1 = RecordWithIntern.CreateOrGetIntern(3);
var c2 = RecordWithIntern.CreateOrGetIntern(3);

Console.WriteLine((c1 == c2)); // true
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(c1, c2)); // true
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(c1,
    RecordWithIntern.CreateOrGetIntern(3))); // true
Console.WriteLine("----");

Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(c1,
       new RecordWithIntern(3))); // false - same as string
Console.WriteLine(c1 == new RecordWithIntern(3)); // true - same as string
Console.WriteLine("----");

RecordWithIntern.ClearCache(); // won't clear since c1 is being kept alive
Console.WriteLine(RecordWithIntern.CacheCount); // 1
GC.KeepAlive(c1);

RecordWithIntern.ClearCache(); // still won't clear because no GC has occurred
Console.WriteLine(RecordWithIntern.CacheCount); // 1
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
RecordWithIntern.ClearCache(); //  will clear finally
Console.WriteLine(RecordWithIntern.CacheCount); // 0

Console.WriteLine("--- Array Tests ---");
// Arrays Tests
TestArray(i => RecordWithIntern.CreateOrGetIntern(i));
// New memory: 803048
// Cache count before GC: 42
// Cache count after GC : 0
Console.WriteLine("---");
TestArray(i => new RecordWithIntern(i));
// New memory: 3200032
// Cache count before GC: 0
// Cache count after GC: 0
Console.WriteLine("---");

const int ARR_SIZE = 100_000;

void TestArray(Func<int, RecordWithIntern> factory) {
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();

    var bytes = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
    var arr = new RecordWithIntern[ARR_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) {
        arr[i] = factory(i % 42);
    }
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
    var newBytes = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
    Console.WriteLine("New memory: " + (newBytes - bytes));

    GC.KeepAlive(arr);
    RecordWithIntern.ClearCache(); // won't clear before GC
    Console.WriteLine("Cache count before GC: " + RecordWithIntern.CacheCount);
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
    RecordWithIntern.ClearCache();

    Console.WriteLine("Cache count after GC: " + RecordWithIntern.CacheCount);
}

Output of the tests (may vary in the exact memory bytes):
--- Simple Tests ---
True
True
True
----
False
True
----
1
1
0
--- Array Tests ---
New memory: 803048
Cache count before GC: 42
Cache count after GC: 0
---
New memory: 3200024
Cache count before GC: 0
Cache count after GC: 0
---

I am still not 100% sure how to implement thread-safety in a more optimal way (especially in the finalizer part), for the time a simple lock object is used every time we are about to use the dictionary. Any comments are welcome.
